# position of string in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find the position of a certain string in a file to know, where I should start editing.

At the moment, I'm using the `re` module to convert a file in a list of bools and get the position with the `index` function.

Question: Is there a better/shorter way to achieve this goal?

---

In this example, I want to find the first line, where the letter "b" appears.

Example file:

```
a
b
c
b
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

infile = open("examplefile","r")
indata = infile.readlines()
infile.close()

finder = re.compile("b")
matches = [True if finder.search(s) else False for s in indata]
print(matches.index(True))
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a generator expression, like this

```
with open("Input.txt") as in_file:
    print(next(idx for idx, line in enumerate(in_file) if "b" in line))
# 1
```

**Note:** This raises `StopIteration` if the string being searched is not found in the file.

Comment: I modified your solution to be able to use regular expressions and the already read file: `print(next(idx for (idx, line) in enumerate(indata) if finder.search(line)))`

Comment: If you have a very large file, you might want to compare how this performs relative to using `mmap` and `re.finditer` with a `bytes` pattern to search through the memory-mapped file.

Comment: @eryksun I was not sure, what the script would do at the end. In its current state, I search two blocks in the file, modify some values and may overwrite the original file. By reading the whole file, I can edit what I want without thinking too much. In the end it is only a convenience script, where performance doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, if it does not have to be perform in python, you may use bash's `grep`.

```
    grep -nr 'string_to_search' your_file
```

It will return the number of line right before your match.